# Use Riesz Fischer to prove a sum of functions is in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We are given a function $g := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_n| $ with the additional property that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_n|^2$ be convergent and $\forall n, f_n \in L^2.$ I need to prove that $g \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ as well. I want to use the Riesz Fischer theorem in proving this. This theorem assures the existence of a function $f$ that is square-integrable and such that $f_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of f. In other words, I need to prove that $f = g.$

I do not understand how you can check if the Fourier coefficients coincide with the functions $f_n$, if $g$ is not given explicitly.Also it is not clear to me the fact that $f_n$ are functions and not constants as in the case of Fourier coefficients.

Can somebody provide a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a missing hypothesis somewhere because if $f_{n}$ is the indicator function of the interval $[n - 1, n)$, then each $f_{n} \in L^{2}$ and $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} |f_{n}|^{2}$ converges since their supports are pairwise disjoint, but $g \notin L^{2}$.

Comment: I think what you want is $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \|f_n\|_2 < \infty.$ In that case, you just have a convergent series in a complete and normed vector space. So the result follow from elementary linear algebra (no Fourier stuff needed).

Comment: Thanks. How one can argue that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|f_n\|_2$ is convergent ? This is the point.